# Limit api GET request depending on user id/token - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I want to return a list of files linked to a User in my database through REST.

For example, return response for user with id of 1 through:

http://localhost:8000/api/files/1/ --> {"file info 1", "file info 2", ...}

However, what I want to ensure is that OTHER users cannot access the above information, since their ID is not 1, i.e If another user has an id of 2, the above URL should respond with Permission Denied.

I understand that DRF has the IsAuthenticated permission, however this lets ALL logged in users potentially have access to other user's file information.

What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DRF Generic Detail View, you could override `get_object()` and add check there

```
def get_object(self):
    user = super(ViewClassName, self).get_object()
    if self.request.user != user:
        raise PermissionDenied
    return user
```

Comment: Can this be done when using a non-django frontend (such as ReactJS or Vue) if the user's ID is stored in localstorage?

Comment: But you're still sending your auth token header to the endpoint, correct? So Django will see your authentication status, and compare your user ID with the ID in the URL.

Comment: It's working now with the get_object override you suggested. Thank you for the suggestion! I have JWT enabled with this, making the API a little more secure!

Answer (score 0):

DRF View has "permission_classes" property. It will be better to prevent this request as a permission.